# Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations error in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-custom-view

I got this error in Android Studio:

> Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations

Code:

```
public class cizim extends View {

    Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public cizim (Context c){
        super(c);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.foto));
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        path.addCircle(x, y, 10, Path.Direction.CW);
        invalidate();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

I got the error with this code:

```
canvas.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.foto));
```

How can I resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: Decode the resource in your constructor and cache the result in a field, instead of decoding on each and every `onDraw()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a view is always a heavy task because `onDraw` method is invoked whenever the view needs to be drawn again, so imagine allocating/creating new objects in that method; it will certainly take a lot of time and will decrease your app performance.

So instead of creating your bitmap every time `onDraw` is called, create it only once in your view constructor.

Add a new instance variable to your class:

```
public class cizim extends View {

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    ...
}
```

Then in your constructor, create that object as follows:

```
public cizim(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.foto);
}
```

Finally modify your `onDraw` method to:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

---

### Edit:

There is actually another issue with your code that will result in `UnsupportedOperationException` when calling `canvas.setBitmap`. If you refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#setBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)), `setBitmap` will change the bitmap the canvas will draw to. Since you need to draw the bitmap on the screen, you cannot use `setBitmap` here. So what you actually need is [canvas.drawBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

Change your `onDraw` method to:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but I got this error : E/AndroidRuntime( 5281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 5281): Process: com.epitcenter.x_ren.paintdeneme, PID: 5281

E/AndroidRuntime( 5281): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

E/AndroidRuntime( 5281):  at android.view.HardwareCanvas.setBitmap(HardwareCanvas.java:39)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5281):  at com.epitcenter.x_ren.paintdeneme.cizim.onDraw(cizim.java:24)